# Getting JS error location when using Jurassic

Tags: .net, jurassic

I'm using the [Jurassic JS engine](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/) to run some JS code in a .NET application. Unfortunately I get an exception when running the code which is caused by some undefined value somewhere. But how can I locate the exact spot? Note that I cannot run it in a different environment because I use methods exported from .NET, so I'd like to find a way to get the location of the runtime error.

I'm loading/evaluating the files using the `ScriptSource` class, so that they do have an attached file name. Still I don't get any output post-mortem - am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try debugging your code as described here: http://jurassic.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Debugging&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: I don't need debugging, I need a way to determine error location when evaluation exception is raised.

Comment: Not sure if this gives you what you want then http://jurassic.codeplex.com/discussions/241774, but if you look at the replies from Paul Bartrum (first and second replies), its saying that you need to wrap your error in a JavaScriptException which will preserve the stack trace for you.

Answer (score 2):

`Jurassic.JavaScriptException.LineNumber` gives error location but only in parsing errors.